# Issue with hover opacity and headers

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

I want my website to have the same effect this website has: [Trask Industries](http://www.trask-industries.com/#/media)

When the upper right image is hovered the text appears and yellow covers the image.

This is the effect I am failing to recreate in CSS and Html, using headers and hover opacity. In my attempts the headers become opaque rather than standing out like on that site. I also don't know how to make the headers appear and disappear on hover.

Here is the [jsfiddle of my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/bzm6T/).

```
.content1:hover, .content2:hover, .content3:hover, .content4:hover, .content5:hover, .content6:hover {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.30;
    transition: .2s;
    webkit-transition: .2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap the h1 and h2 in a div, and you would animate that div in css.
I also added a same class for the contents.
Here is an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bzm6T/2/

Basically, this is the updated code:

Code:

```css
.contents:hover > div {
      color: black;
      opacity: 1;
}

.contents div {
 opacity: 0;
 display: block;
 width: 100%; height: 100%;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <a href="articleF.html" class="contents content1">
        <div>
            <h1>The Low Stakes of Modern life</h1>
            <h2>Default 1Default 1Default 1Default 1Default 1Default 1</h2>
        </div>

    </a>

    <a href="articleA1.html" class="contents content2">
        <div>
            <h1>AARON SWARTZ</h1>
            <h2>Cats Can Puuuuur</h2>
        </div>

    </a>

    <a href="articleA2.html" class="contents content3">
        <div>
            <h1>JOBILLY BOOP</h1>
            <h2>Cats Can Puuuuur</h2>
        </div>

    </a>

    <a href="articleD.html" class="contents content4">
        <div>
            <h1>Content4</h1>
            <h2>Cats Can Puuuuur</h2>
        </div>

    </a>

    <a href="articleK1.html" class="contents content5">
        <div>
            <h1>Content5</h1>
            <h2>Cats Can Puuuuur</h2>
        </div>

    </a>
    <a href="articleK1.html" class="contents Content6">
        <div>
            <h1>Content6</h1>
            <h2>Cats Can Puuuuur</h2>
        </div>

    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: You have no idea the frustration you have saved me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach, but basically the same with CSS transition: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z8Dve/)

```
.holder {
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.leftdiv {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.picdiv {
    float: right;
    background-color: orange;
}
.picdiv img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.picdiv img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```